# Resize parent view if subview changes size

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, resize, nsview

I'm new to Cocoa and I'm programming a custom `InspectorView`.
A parent view (`InspectorView`) contains several subviews (`InspectorCategories`).

If I uncollapse a category  (subview) I have to resize/relayout my parents view?
I found out that this is not possible through autoresize masks - Is this correct?

I tried it with `resizeSubviewsWithOldSize` in my parents view but this gets not called while resizing the subview.

How can I achieve this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not possible to do through autoresizing masks. Autoresizing mask defines how the view is resized when its superview changes bounds.

The subview should let its superview know what size it needs, for example through a delegate call. The superview then should resize itself and the subview.

Answer (score 2):

There are two parts to accomplish what I think you want:

(a) In the parent view, override the [sizeThatFits:](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/sizeThatFits%3a) method so that it computes a new size that fits around the resized subview.

(b) In the subview, override the setFrame: method and after the frame size is changed, it calls [self.superview sizeToFit] to resize the superview, perhaps like this:

```
-(void)setFrame:(CGRect)newFrame
{
    [super setFrame:newFrame];
    [self.superview sizeToFit];
}
```

Comment: This is an good approach for UIViews. However, there are no such methods in NSView.